# Clustering with ColdFusion

Tags: cluster, coldfusion

Soon we are going to be deploying our webapp built on ColdFusion. We were thinking about clustering ColdFusion however there are a couple questions I have.

1) Is ColdFusion clustering with JRUN good for high performance applications? If So how do you clustering horizontally?

2) Is it possible to cluster Tomcat and have ColdFusion running on each node?

Thanks,
Faisal Abid

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have an answer to the specific question, but if nobody has one here you might also check with the cf-talk mailing list at houseoffusion.com.  There are some knowledgeable people on that list who can likely answer this for you.

Comment: Faisal, if you are talking about clustering for availability with _session replication_ then there are a lot of factors to consider - and hardware will be a primary issue. It's not for the faint of heart. If by cluster you mean identical instances for load balancing then it's relatively easy. Folks mean a lot of different things when they say "cluster" - I apologize if you already know all this :)

Answer (score 1):

Clustering is pretty good with Jrun.  Coldfusion 10 is moving to Tomcat so it will be even better.  My recommendation is to get setup using Tomcat since your' thinking about it anyways.

Remember that you can deploy your CF app inside of any J2EE server as a jar/war/car.

As for Tomcat, they have a ton of resources out there including clustering that might better answer your questions about their clustering, give it a search.